# Convert date from dd-month-yy to yyyyMMdd in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Is there an easier way to convert a date from **07-Jan-15** to **20150107** in SSIS without using the **REPLACE** method or Conditional logic?

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Comment: Yes I just used the REPLACE method

Comment: What is your source, what are the field types and what SQL Server version are you using? Dates don't have formats, strings do. If your target column is a datetime/date field, you need to parse the input as a date, not convert it to another string.  If both fields are date typed (eg the source is a MySQL database with a date field), you should read the field as a date, not string.

Comment: If your source really is a string, you should use the Data Conversion transformation or the Derived Column transformation to parse the input and convert it to date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the source is in string format and destination will be numeric. In the Derived Column I just used REPLACE method in the Expression field but it feels sloppy coding

Comment: You could use a script transformation to do date conversions in C# or VB, if that would make you feel better.